# build up dictionary by replacing - python

Tags: python

I want to get a code to change a certain string, then added something .

For instance,
(Here, target_word = "Python" , tag = i

I want to get

[image]

But instead , I kept getting the word "Python" with a "/" ??
[image]

Here is my code, at where do I do wrong ?? And actually it is my whole part of code,

```
def insert_tag(input_filename, output_filename, tag, target_word):

    output = open(output_filename, 'w')

    for line in open(input_filename) :
        output.write(line.replace(target_word,"<"+tag+">"+target_word+"<"+"/"+tag+ ">" ))
    output.close()    
print("Testing Part II")
print("Testing insert_tag() with input_filename = 'sample1.html', output_filename = 'modified1.html', "
      + "tag = 'i', target_word = 'Python'")
insert_tag('sample1.html', 'modified1.html', 'i', 'Python')
print()
```

Input File :
[image]

[image]

Output(after coding should be ):

[image]

[image]

Comment: @J.Done I copied your code identically from here into a python file and used a html file with the contents `<html><head></head><body style="font-size:20pt"><p>Python</p><p>I like Python</p><p>No change</p></body></html>` and I couldn't replicate this, can you show your input and output files *contents*

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 I agree that the way the OP is doing `open(input_filename)` isn't good, but doing `open(input_filename).readlines()` is even worse because it needlessly reads the whole file into a list of lines.

Comment: I don't see how you could be getting this error from the code you posted. BTW, you should calculate `target_word,"<"+tag+">"+target_word+"<"+"/"+tag+ ">" ` outside the loop. It's inefficient to re-calculate the same constant on every single line you read.

Comment: @J.Done I don't want to know what the output ***should be*** I want to know what ***it is***, and please just copy the contents as text, don't insert it as an image

Comment: Sorry, I can't paste PNG files into my text editor. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also, what does this question have to do with dictionaries? I don't see any dictionaries in your code.

Comment: @NickA Is what I updated correctly??

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>I Like Python</h1>

<p> I love Python, because Python is awesome! I love Python yay! </p>
<p> This paragraph should remain unchanged. </p>
</body>
<html>

@NickA

Comment: @J.Done Yes I got the correct output with that input, can you [Edit] the contents of your modified1.html file into the question

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>I Like <i>Python</i></h1>

<p> I love <i>Python</i>, because <i>Python</i> is awesome! I love <i>Python</i> yay! </p>
<p> This paragraph should remain unchanged. </p>
</body>
<html>

@NickA

Comment: @J.Done What browser are you using? That output is correct and displays as it should, I see no extra slashes

Comment: I am using google chrome ,

Comment: And when I try different browser , I still see slashes

Comment: @J.Done Try opening your output html file again, make sure the problem is still there ***if that truly is the contents of your modified1.html file***

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157699/discussion-between-j-done-and-nick-a).